# How to draw gridlines for ECG graph plot using MPChart Android

Tags: android, kotlin, graph, charts, mpandroidchart

I am developing an application to show ECG waveform in an android application. I tried using MPAndroidchart and XYPlotlibrary to plot the ECG data. I can able to see Major grid lines, but my requirement is to show both Major and minor gridlines So that it will resemble Ecg graph paper. Can anyone have any suggestion or suggest any library to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to draw minor grid lines using a built-in chart capability with MPAndroidChart, but you can still add them manually to get the desired appearance.

For example:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val chart = findViewById<LineChart>(R.id.chart)


    val lines = mutableListOf<LineDataSet>()

    val x = (0..100).map { i -> 0.1f*i }
    val y = x.map { i -> 5*sin(7*i)*sin(0.5f*i)* cos(3.25f*i) }

    val primaryLine = LineDataSet(x.zip(y).map { Entry(it.first, it.second) }, "primary")
    primaryLine.setDrawCircles(false)
    primaryLine.lineWidth = 3f
    primaryLine.color = Color.RED
    primaryLine.setDrawValues(false)
    primaryLine.isHighlightEnabled = false

    val majorX = 2f
    val majorY = 4f
    val minorX = majorX/5
    val minorY = majorY/5

    val xmin = floor(x.min()/majorX)*majorX
    val xmax = ceil(x.max()/majorX)*majorX
    val ymin = floor(y.min()/majorY)*majorY
    val ymax = ceil(y.max()/majorY)*majorY

    xGridLines(lines, minorX, ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax, false)
    yGridLines(lines, minorY, ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax, false)

    xGridLines(lines, majorX, ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax, true)
    yGridLines(lines, majorY, ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax, true)

    lines.add(primaryLine)

    chart.axisRight.isEnabled = false
    val yAx = chart.axisLeft
    yAx.setDrawLabels(false)
    yAx.setDrawGridLines(false)
    yAx.setDrawAxisLine(false)
    yAx.axisMinimum = ymin
    yAx.axisMaximum = ymax

    val xAx = chart.xAxis
    xAx.setDrawLabels(false)
    xAx.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
    xAx.setDrawGridLines(false)
    xAx.setDrawAxisLine(false)
    xAx.axisMinimum = xmin
    xAx.axisMaximum = xmax+0.01f

    chart.data = LineData(lines.toList())
    chart.description.isEnabled = false
    chart.legend.isEnabled = false
}

private fun yGridLines(lines: MutableList<LineDataSet>, spacing: Float, ymin: Float, ymax: Float, xmin: Float, xmax: Float, major: Boolean) {
    val nY = ((ymax-ymin)/spacing).roundToInt()
    for(i in 0..nY) {
        val yl = ymin + i*spacing
        val ep = listOf(Entry(xmin,yl), Entry(xmax,yl))
        lines.add(makeGridLineDataSet(ep, major))
    }
}

private fun xGridLines(lines: MutableList<LineDataSet>, spacing: Float, ymin: Float, ymax: Float, xmin: Float, xmax: Float, major: Boolean) {
    val nX = ((xmax-xmin)/spacing).roundToInt()
    for(i in 0..nX) {
        val xl = xmin + i*spacing
        val ep = listOf(Entry(xl, ymin), Entry(xl,ymax))
        lines.add(makeGridLineDataSet(ep, major))
    }
}

private fun makeGridLineDataSet(e: List<Entry>, major: Boolean): LineDataSet {
    val ds = LineDataSet(e,"")
    ds.setDrawCircles(false)
    if( major ) {
        ds.color = Color.BLACK
        ds.lineWidth = 1f
    }
    else {
        ds.color = Color.BLACK
        ds.lineWidth = 0.5f
        ds.enableDashedLine(10f,10f,0f)
    }
    ds.setDrawValues(false)
    ds.isHighlightEnabled = false
    return ds
}
```

Which produces

[image: grid line demo]

Comment: Hi Tyler, Thanks for your response. I can see the grid lines when using your function. But my requirement is I need to plot a single data at a time, so that it will be visible as like a ecg graph. Can you tell me how to animate and plot data like that

Comment: Your question was "how to show grid lines". If you have other questions about animating data please ask a separate question.